# Digits of a number in arithmetic progression

Tags: permutations, combinations

Let the digits $a, b, c$ be in A.P. Nine-digit numbers are to be formed using each of these three digits thrice such that three consecutive digits are in A.P. at least once. How many such numbers can be formed?

I figured out that they want permutations of $aaabbbccc$ such that it must contain atleast one of the following groups atleast once:
$abc, cba, aaa, bbb, ccc.$

But how to proceed? I have tried using principle of inclusion and exclusion but nothing has worked out. Please guide.

Comment: This is not clear at all.  If, say, $(a,b,c)=(2,4,6)$ then what would be an example of your $9-$digit number?

Comment: As per the question, a,b and c are FIXED single-digit distinct numbers; we need not worry about their values.

Comment: If we take them to be 2,4,6; then we need to find permutations of 222444666 satisfying the condition given in the question, which is, the number must contain atleast 3 consecutive digits in AP. So atleast 1 of 246, 642, 222, 444, 666 must be present in the number atleast once

Comment: Ah.  I think that anyone reading "consecutive digits" would assume you meant $d,d+1,d+2$.  As it is, I have no guess what you mean by it.  If you can define it, I suggest adding your definition to your post.

Comment: By "consecutive digits", I obviously mean that the 3 digits are one-after-another, occuring in the 9-digit number. Like in the number abcaabbcc, abc form a triplet of consecutive digits (which occur at 1st, 2nd and 3rd position respectively). Also, a,b and c are in AP. I need to count such 9-digit numbers where I'll find ATLEAST ONE such triplet of consecutive digits, whose numbers, in the order in which they occur in the 9-digit number, form an AP. I'm sorry if that was not clear from the language of the question. Please guide me how to do it.

Comment: Well ,Inclusion Exclusion does appear to be the way to go.  You are helped by the fact that, if $XYZ$ is a "good" block of three then it is not possible for  $YZW$ to be a good block, though $Z$ could be the start of a second good block, as in $\cdots 24666\cdots$

Comment: Yes you are right; but how do I do it then?

Comment: Brute force, I think.  Just start by counting the words such that any given block of three is good, then subtract those such that any two given blocks of three are good, and so on.  Like I say, it's annoying that the blocks can overlap non-trivially.  Are you quite sure they didn't simply mean blocks of the form $abc$ or $cba$?  If that was the case, then overlap would clearly not be possible.  Both are valid questions, clearly, but the overlap cases complicate the count.

Comment: Frankly, with only $\frac {9!}{(3!)^3}=1680$ possible words, I'd be inclined to ask a machine to list all of them and check.  Inclusion Exclusion ought to work but it will be extremely messy and error prone.

Comment: No it's nowhere written that the favourable blocks are just abc or cba only. So they can be aaa, bbb or ccc as well. I tried to do it by first counting cases where ATLEAST ONE of abc or cba occurs (Total cases − cases where none of them occurs). Then adding the cases where aaa, bbb or ccc or both or all three of them occur but abc and cba do not occur. It is a VERY LENGTHY approach

Comment: This question was asked as an integer type question in a high school level exam. So we cannot do it using any computer:) It had to be done in 3-4 mins.

Comment: Huh.  That's interesting.  Maybe there's some quick way to see what the bad words are.  They exist...as in $aabbccacb$  I don't see a cheap way to enumerate those...but if there is a super fast way to do it, I think it would be along those lines.

Comment: Please keep trying to find an easier and shorter way to do it. I'm also doing the same. Do write it here if you get it. Thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer would change if $0$ is a member of this AP vs when it is not so I assumed non zero digits and found the answer for them. if $a,b$ and $c$ are distinct single digit members of AP then in the $9$ digit number the possible subsequences are $abc , aaa, bbb,ccc$ or $cba$ as you have listed. Let us have set $S_1$ which contains all the cases having $abc/bca$ pattern in the number and $S_2$ which contains numbers having no $abc/bca$ type pattern but having $aaa/bbb/ccc$ type pattern. $n(S_1) +n(S_2)$ is our answer

$S_1$ : [image]
This is how I've computed $n(S_1)$,

Numbers that have at least one $abc$ is given by $\frac{7!}{2!2!2!}$ but the problem in this is that we have overcounted the numbers having two/three $abc$ hence we subtract numbers having at least $2$ $abc$ i.e $\frac{5!}{2!}$ and then add one $(abcabcabc)$ . this sums up to $571$

$n(S_1) = n($at least $1$ $abc)$ + $n($at least $1$ $cba)$ - $n(2 abc$ $1$ $cba)$ - $n(2$ $cba$ $1$ $abc)$ - $n(1$ $abc$ $1$ $cba)$.

I calculated the blue region i.e $n(2$ $abc$ $1$ $cba)$ = $n(2$ cba $1 abc)$ $=13$

Then $n(1$ $abc$ $1$ $cba)$ (yellow):

This can exist as

- $..abcba..$
- $..cbabc..$
- $..abc..cba..$

For $1$st case you arrange $"abcba"$ in $|b|a|c|c|$ ("|" means gaps) by $5\choose{1}$ $\times$ $\frac{4!}{2!}$ . So now you have to observe that this arrangement can produce all elements from the blue regions except those numbers that can be partitioned into $3$ different APs(example: $abccbaabc$, $abcabccba$ but not $caabcbabc$).Ways that these exceptional numbers that can be partitioned into $3$ different APs is $3\choose1$. Hence the first case is $5\choose1$ $\times$ $\frac{4!}{2!} - (13 -3) = 50$

Then, Number of $2$nd case elements $=$ Number of $1$st case elements $= 50$

Third case is permuting $"abc"$ and $"cba"$ into $|a|b|c|$ which is $4\choose2$ $\times$ $3!$ $\times$ $2! = 72$

$\implies n(1 \ abc \  1 \ cba) = 50 + 50 + 72 = 172$

$\therefore n(S_1) = 571 + 571 - 13 - 13 -172 = 944$

$S_2$: This is a bit tricky, you have to make $2$ different cases that is:

- when $aaa$ occurs
- when $ccc$ occurs

You compute cases where both $aaa$ and $abc/cba$ pattern is formed and do the same thing with $ccc$. Then subtract these cases from the total cases where $aaa/ccc/bbb$ cases exist

hence, cases where both $aaa$ and $abc/cba$ occur i.e
$$C' = C(..aaabc..) + C(..cbaaa..) - C(..cbaaabc..)$$

$$C'= \frac{5!}{2!2!} + \frac{5!}{2!2!} - 3! = 54$$
Cases with $ccc$ and $abc/cba$ are also $54$ by symmetry.

However we also have those case where it hs both aaa and ccc and it has been double counted i.e $..aaabccc.. and ..cccbaaa..$ $i.e = 6$

$T$ = Cases where $aaa/bbb/ccc$ type pattern is formed
Again you can count this by $PIE$:

$$(\frac{7! \times 3}{3!3!}) - \frac{5! \times 3}{3!} + 3! = 366$$

$n(S_2) = T - 2C'+ 6= 264$

Therefore total cases$ = 944 + 264 = 1208 $

**PS:** I took $20$ minutes to get to the answer and $30$ minutes to type it out, It is better to skip such a question in $JEE$

Comment: I think your answer is absolutely correct, I got the same answer 1208 using a computer program. But the correct answer as given in the Final Answer Key is 944

Comment: K so I guess they don't consider aaa as an AP, which is wrong

Comment: Yes, you have clearly separated the two cases in your answer. Thank you very much

Comment: "Third case is permuting "abc" and "cba" into |a|b|c|" doesn't this overcount a couple of cases from the blue region? Like abcabccba for example.